# If quantum entanglement causes the violations of Bell's inequality why don't we see perfect correlation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, non-locality

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement):

> For example, if a pair of entangled particles is generated such that
> their total spin is known to be zero, and one particle is found to
> have clockwise spin on a first axis, then the spin of the other
> particle, measured on the same axis, is found to be counterclockwise.

Yet the Bell tests all observe a [lesser correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test):

> If S is numerically greater than 2 it has infringed the CHSH
> inequality. The experiment is declared to have supported the QM
> prediction and ruled out all local hidden variable theories.

Is there any way to run an experiment that could observe (near) perfect correlation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [Tsirelson's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson%27s_bound) states that, e.g., the value of $2\sqrt{2}$ obtained for the CHSH inequality is optimal within quantum theory, while the maximum value obtainable within all theories which cannot communicate instantly (no-signalling theories) would be 4.

Comment: Thanks, from the link: _Significant research has been dedicated to finding a physical principle that explains why quantum correlations go only up to the Tsirelson bound and nothing more._ I gather then that quantum entanglement is not "perfect", it sometimes happens and other times not?

Comment: This has nothing to do with entanglement being perfect. Even perfect entanglement does not give you the maximal violation of Bell's inequality. If that's your definition of "perfect", then go with it, but I don't see a reason to do so. The wikipedia quote certainly does not justify your conclusion.

Comment: The point is that quantum theory - in fact, *any* theory where expectation values are associated to observables, and observables at different positions have to commute - cannot go beyond this bound. In some sense, this is rather perfect. (It has also been argued that this follows from rotational invariance of the theory, if I don't misremember  https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611001, so only a theory without the notion of continuous rotations - like classical bits - can give a larger violation.)

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstand the details of the test statistic and design of that particular type of experiment. By perfect I mean that the first wikipedia quote is accurate. Does that conservation of spin _always_ happen when particles are entangled, or only sometimes?

Comment: For the first quote you give, there *is* perfect entanglement which *always* gives perfect anticorrelation. But this is nothing quantum mechanical, you can observe perfect (anti-)correlation everywhere in our classical lives. (Just search for "Bertlmann's socks".) What is wrong is that you seem to assume that Bell tests measure the same type of correlations - they don't, they are designed to measure specifically quantum mechanical correlations (again, check Bertlmann's socks).

Comment: Thanks. For anyone in the future: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00220688/document

Comment: @Livid To be fair, I didn't mean to suggest to read the original paper; there is enough other information on the point of the socks on the internet, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhold_Bertlmann#Bertlmann%E2%80%99s_socks

Comment: One last question if I may. The entanglement always occurs but in the experiment described there the correlation is expected to be less than one only at intermediate angles: _Thus the ad hoc model does what is required of it (i.e., reproduces
quantum mechanical results) only at (a - b) = 0, (a - b) = s/2 and
(a - b) = n, but not at intermediate angles._ This is based on a "short calculation" that is not shown so I don't see the assumptions. But is there no experiment that can show perfect correlation that distinguishes between quantum entanglement effects vs not?